# AWS MSK Cloud Formation Tags problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When creating `AWS::MSK::Cluster` with Cloud Formation I am not able to set `Tags` in the usual way:

```
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref Identifier
```

Because of this error:

`Property validation failure: [Value of property {/Tags} does not match type {Map}]`

As of the time of writing, the documentation states that, instead of the usual `Type: List of Tag`, I should use: `Type: Json`.

Also the same documentation states that:

`You can specify tags in JSON or in YAML, depending on which format you use for your template`

Answer (score 8):

After further investigation (and AWS support help), the working (only on creation) example looks like this:

```
Tags:
  Name: !Ref Identifier
```

Additionally, tags cannot be modified (the docs actually state that tags change **require replacement**), when tried a slightly confusing error shows up:

`CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename kafka-eu-west-1-dev and update the stack again.`

Comment: I hit this as well. MSK cloudformation support needs a touch of work it seems.